# Connect to Spring Cloud Config Server that has SSL enabled

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I am running spring cloud config server in a ECS cluster in AWS. It is fronted by a route 53 endpoint exposed on a HTTPS port.I have created a test client to connect to the cloud config server and it is returning the error below -

java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching xxxxx found.

I see the same error when I try to hit a config server running on my local machine. I enabled ssl for my local config server using the settings below in bootstrap.yml

**server setting**

```
server:
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:certs/qa/clientid.jks
    key-password: weblogic
    key-store-password: weblogic
```

**client setting**

```
server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:certs/qa/cacerts
server.ssl.trust-store-password=changeit
```

I am trying to ignore the name validation by setting NoopHostnameVerifier in RestTemplate. However this seems to be executed only after the connection is tried to established to Spring Cloud Config Server. Is there a way to update ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator before connection is tried to be established to spring cloud config server?

```
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnClass;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass({ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.class, RestTemplate.class})
public class ConfigClientBootstrapConfiguration {

    private final ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator locator;

    @Autowired
    public ConfigClientBootstrapConfiguration(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator locator) {
        System.out.println("Setting Locator");
        this.locator = locator;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Setting Resttemplate");
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier()).build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
        RestTemplate restTemplate =  new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

        locator.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
    }

}
```

bootstrap.factories (in resources/META-INF)

```
# Bootstrap components
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=<package>.ConfigClientBootstrapConfiguration
```

Comment: How was the cert generated?  Does it have the SAN entry?  To be valid, the cert needs a FQDN in DNS and in the cert SAN entry.

Comment: I used an existing truststore and keystore that was being used by other apps in the project. I am not sure how the underlying certificate was generated. How can verify the SAN entry?

Comment: Use `openssl x509 -in yourcert -noout -text`.  Or look at cert details in browser.

Comment: To look at the cert for this site in your browser, click the green lock, view cert - details Certificate Subject Alt Name.  There are a whole bunch of DNS Name wildcard entries.

Comment: I see DNS in SAN when I view the certificate. The certificate also states "Issued by: Amazon"

Comment: the dns in san in the certificate is different from one that I am trying to hit.

Comment: Hi @Punter Vicky, have you found a way do fix this issue? If yes, can you please share it?